# What name is given to this text encoding?

Tags: encoding

```
"\x3c" => '<' (open bracket)
"\x3e" => '>' (close bracket)
"\x3d" => '=' (equal)
```

What name is given to the encoding method used above? (`\x~~`)

It seems to not be URL encoding. It could be a type of utf-8 encoding, but I don't know.

Comment: The encoding is ASCII. (Perhaps you meant to ask about the literal notation?)

Comment: is that name is 'literal notation'?

Comment: The literal notation in many languages is that strings of characters are enclosed in `""` (quotation marks). Further, a single character can be expressed in terms of its numerical value, represented hexadecimally, using the character literal `\xNN`. So you've written three strings consisting of one character each, respectively of values 60, 61 and 62.

Comment: i found a answer. name of above syntax is "Standard Numeric Format Strings" : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.95%29.aspx thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used in literals in e.g. programming languages. [wikipedia knows it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Programming_and_data_formats)

Comment: i found a answer. name of above syntax is "Standard Numeric Format Strings" : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.95%29.aspx thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an encoding in the sense of a character encoding (e.g. UTF-8, ANSI, etc.).
It's the syntax used to express hexadecimal character literals in many programming languages.

Comment: i found a answer. name of above syntax is "Standard Numeric Format Strings" : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.95%29.aspx thanks.

Comment: If you read the MSDN article you linked to, you'll see that the so called "Standard Numeric Format Strings" are something altogether different.